# Size of SQS messages

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm sending messages to SQS using the AWS-SDK for JavaScript. Each message needs to be 256kb in size tops.

Each message is a JSON object that gets decoded on another service.

Option 1: JSON Object as string: Count length and make sure it's less than  262144?

```
function* getStuff(rows, someConfig) {
  let totesPayload = 0
  let payload = []
  for (const row of rows) {
   const singleItemInPayload = rowToPayload(row, someConfig)
   if (singleItemInPayload.length + totesPayload < 262144 - (enclosingObjectSize())) {
     payload.push(singleItemInPayload)
     totesPayload += singleItemInPayload.length
   } else {
     yield({ payload })
     payload = []
   }
}
```

Option 2: Buffer.from(JSON Object as string): Count length of JSON Object and make sure it's less than  262144?

Most of the data is text, so I'm not sure I'm going to get any good help from putting it in a byte array.

Is option 2 necessary?

Comment: JavaScript strings are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units (like in Java, .NET, VB4/5/6, VBA, VBScript, NTFS, NVARCHAR, …). So, `length` will give you the count of UTF-16 code units. (@MatthewPope is [saying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51694154/2226988) that UTF-16 is not the relevant encoding.) If you need to count bytes then you need to apply the relevant encoding (though for UTF-16, you can count on each code unit being two bytes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQS uses UTF-8 for strings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html), so if any part of your message can contain non-ASCII characters, then you will need to measure the size by converting to bytes because [UTF-8 is a variable width encoding which uses 1 to 4 bytes for a single character](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).